# Curl Does not follow Header redirects

Tags: php, curl

this is  my current code. the the follow location is not working. why?

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $_SERVER);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ste);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Because you're passing `$_SERVER` variable to HTTP headers. Learn something about format of HTTP header.

Comment: I removed it. but I still get the same data